# Errors when creating Android projects in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've recently had to re-install all my SDKs etc. on my new HDD, and I'm getting errors trying to work with newly created Android Projects in Eclipse.

I installed the JDK, I installed Eclipse, I installed the Android SDK, I installed the ADT Plugin for Eclipse.

I had some errors with the Android SDK Manager (Access Denied to downloaded files so no updates being made) which appear to be fixed by selecting 'Run as Administrator'

When I create a new Android Project in Eclipse, the project appears to create successfully, however R.java is not being generated and I am getting the message "The project target (Android 2.3.3) was not properly loaded."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like file privileges issue. Run as Administrator to lunch Eclipse and try again. If it works, try to give yourselves good enough priv to mount point of your new HDD.

Comment: Ahhh yes, thank you! For some reason I thought it already was Running As Administrator. Bah! :)